# .Net Core 2.0 схемы аутентификации

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Мне нужно написать back-end с двумя типами аутентификации: `JWT` для обычных пользователей и `Cookie` для администраторов. Я знаю, что это делается очень просто, нужно в классе `Startup` написать что-то похожее на это:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           })
        .AddJwtBearer()
        .AddCookie();
```

Конкретно мне не понятно, где узнать, какие схемы аутентификации бывают или как настроить схему под себя? Как написать, что посетитель с ролью `user` авторизуется через `JWT`, а `admin` через `Cookie`?
Очень жалко, что нет учебника где было бы все подробно расписано.
Пока что нашел как осуществить миграцию с .net core 1.x на 2.x, там приведены некоторые схемы аутентификации, но не такие которые нужны мне. Вот [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1#replace-getexternalauthenticationschemes).
Еще нашел как совместить Identity и JWT аутентификацию, но там все равно не то что нужно. Вот [ссылка](https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8).

Answer (score 2):

> какие схемы аутентификации бывают

Отправлю к трём замечательным вопросам на ru so:

- [Что именно идентифицирует посетителя сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739684/213987)
- [Исчерпывающее руководство по form-based website authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515309/213987)
- [Как правильно “готовить” авторизацию в SPA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/851781/213987)

> Как написать, что посетитель с ролью user авторизуется через JWT, а admin через Cookie?

Сама постановка задачи говорит о том, что вы путаете процесс аутентификации и авторизации.

- Идентификация — процесс определения, что за человек перед нами.
- Аутентификация — процесс подтверждения, что этот человек именно тот, за кого себя выдает.
- Авторизация — процесс принятия решения о том, что именно этой аутентифицированной персоне разрешается делать.

Поэтому фраза "авторизуется через JWT" некоректна: JWT/cookie - это процесс аутентификации. То есть приходит пользователь, приносит куки или токен и говорит "я есть Пупкин".

Поэтому в принципе вы не можете уже после определения роли указать, каким аутентификационным механизмом пользоваться.

Но можно поступить чуть иначе. ;)

Допустим, у вас есть механизм аутентификации по JWT (см. метод Auth класса 
AccountController).

Вы можете не только при principal == null отдавать 401, но и отдавать 403 если principal не пустой, но содержит claim имеющий claimType=Role со значением admin. То есть не отдавать админам токен.

Или если подобный запрет нужно более точечно сделать - указать схему авторизации только в нужных местах:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему не корректно авторизироваться через JWT? Там можно хранить данные о роли.

Comment: @John У топикстартера вопрос о выборе из двух методов, при этом выбор делается на основе данных которые будут известны ПОСЛЕ выполнения метода. Этакий unzip.zip А в целом если у вас один метод - только JWT, то почему конечно же можно.